# Not able to connect to flask app hosted on kubernetes with minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, flask, minikube

I have created a flask app which I then made an image out of using Docker.
I have the deployment file here.
**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: flask-web-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: flask-web-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: flask-web-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: flask-web-app
        image: flask-web-image
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

I tried a nodeport service which did not work when I tried the address. I have also created a load balancer service using the addon metallb but that did not work either. 
**loadbalancer-service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: flask-web-app-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: flask-web-app
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 5000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Using `kubectl port-forward deployment/flask-web-app 5000:5000` I am able to connect to the website at http://localhost:5000 but I would rather use the loadbalancer.
I configured the metallb addon using `minikube addons configure metallb` and this is the result.

```
Name:         config
Namespace:    metallb-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  <none>

Data
====
config:
----
address-pools:
- name: default
  protocol: layer2
  addresses:
  - 192.168.39.233-192.168.39.240


BinaryData
====

Events:  <none>
```

I used `kubectl get service -n flask-app` to get the external Ip.

```
NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      PORT(S)        AGE
flask-web-app-service   LoadBalancer   10.110.148.162   192.168.39.233   80:32608/TCP   132m
```

The link I use is http://192.168.39.233:80.

I have also tried using `minikube service flask-web-app-service -n flask-app --url` which gave me http://192.168.39.228:32608 but that failed also.

The output of `minikube ip` is 192.168.39.228

Comment: Does the Flask application work in plain Docker, without Kubernetes?  What is the exact URL you're trying to connect to?

Comment: Yes the app runs perfect in Docker. I updated the question when you have chance to take a look thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce it with the following commands and an example flask app, and it only worked after I run the `minikube tunnel` [here are the docs about it](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/commands/tunnel/).

Maybe you can try them with your flask app image instead of the `digitalocean/flask-helloworld` :D

```bash
# Start the cluster with metallb enable
minikube start --addons=metallb

# Configure metallb ranges
minikube addons configure metallb

# Check metallb is configure correctly
kubectl describe configmap config -n metallb-system

# Creating a deployment with a hello world in flask
kubectl create deployment flask-web-app --image=digitalocean/flask-helloworld --port=5000

# Expose the deployment with LoadBalancer
kubectl expose deployment flask-web-app --type=LoadBalancer --port=80 --target-port=5000

# Creates a route to services deployed with type LoadBalancer 
# you can find more about this here 
# https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#loadbalancer-access
minikube tunnel
```

Also I am wondering: Which is the host OS? Which is your minikube version?
Are the deployment and the service in the same namespace?
Because in the command there's a `-n flask-app` but in the manifests there no namespace defined.